# parse a string and truncate it

Tags: javascript

I want to break the following string at the word To and then truncate the email address that follows at 15 characters using JavaScript. This is the sentence:

```
Please email this card to email@emailaddress.com
```

It should like like this:

```
Please email this card 
to email@emailadd...
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. I'm not entirely sure how complex you want to make this?  Are you looking for validation, or are you given a string with an already known format?

Answer (score 1):

does your truncation need to be at the word "To" or just at a certain position?

you might want to look at different javascript functions like

- [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) to get a part of a string
- [charAt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charAt.asp) to return the character at position x.
- [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexOf.asp) to find the position at which a certain piece occurs.

for the truncation of the email-address, you might use a regular expression to find and possibly replace parts of it by certain characters.

if this doesn't help you, please tell us more about the pattern you would like to use for truncation of your text.

regards

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
var input = "Please email this card to email@emailaddress.com";
var toPos = input.indexOf(' to ');
var output = input.substr(0, toPos) + '\r\n' + input.substr(toPos + 1).substr(0, 17) + '...';
```

output:

```
Please email this card
to email@emailadd...
```